# SQL join rows into one

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
| fk | red | brown | green |
|1337|  1  |   0   |   0   |
|1337|  0  |   1   |   0   |
|1337|  0  |   0   |   1   |
```

In tSql how would i return these as one row to say that 1337 has been red, brown and green at some point?

```
| fk | red | brown | green |
|1337|  1  |   1   |   1   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Max` function `Grouping by fk`

```
select fk, max(red) red, max(brown) brown, max(green) green
from yourTable
group by fk
```

If *`red`*, *`brown`* & *`green`* are *`bit type`* fields then try as below

```
select fk, max(red+0) red, max(brown+0) brown, max(green+0) green
from yourTable
group by fk
```

Answer (score 2):

By grouping :

```
Select  fk , 
        Max(red) as red,
        Max(brown) as brown, 
        Max(green) as green 
FROM    myTableName
GROUP   BY fk
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
SELECT  fk
       ,MAX(red)
       ,MAX(brown)
       ,MAX(green)
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY fk
```